# How exactly were solid-fuel rockets added to the parachute lines of the Voskhod capsule?

Tags: landing, soviet-union, parachute, voskhod-program

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36785/12102) notes that Voskhod:

> ...added a small solid-fuel rocket to the parachute lines. It fired as the descent module neared touchdown, providing a softer landing.

How exactly did they safely and reliably add a "solid-fuel rocket to the parachute lines"? I'm thinking that the rocket's exhaust could burn and sever the line directly below, defeating the purpose.

Comment: Rockets pulling on lines have long been a thing.  Check out the unbelievable Stanley Yankee ejection system. https://youtu.be/8Yw8g1Soigk?t=45

Comment: @OrganicMarble enjoying the video, made my morning!

Comment: An engineer from Stanley gave a presentation to our aerospace engineering society when I was in college. I've never forgotten it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I [found a diagram](http://ssi.org/reading/ssi-newsletter-archive/ssi-newsletters-1990-1112/) that explains it better than words. The landing rocket module was at the base of the parachute lines, not above them:

[image]

The linkage appears to be hinged, but I'm guessing it's a solid piece of metal rather than easily-burned fiber.

According to Space Biology & Medicine: Space and its Exploration, the capsule would be falling at 7-8 m/s (~25 fps) on the parachutes, and the rocket would slow it to 3-5 m/s (~13 fps), so impact would have been survivable, if not pleasant, if the rockets didn't activate for any reason.

Comment: Great diagram!!

Comment: "Mechanical altimeter" - So a stick that pokes into the ground?

Comment: Hey, it was good enough for the Apollo LM...

Comment: @MarkusAppel Presumably. But, being certified for space flight, it would have been a very expensive stick.

Comment: What would have happened to the mechanical altimeter if the landing spot was not solid ground but a small lake? But the possibility of hitting water in the desert was very low.

Comment: Hopefully any surface soft enough to avoid triggering the altimeter would be soft enough to safely land on without the rockets.